# mocking multipart mime request with mockito

Tags: java, web-services, junit, mockito, mime-message

I'm pretty new to Mockito and mocking out servlets for testing.  I'm having problems mocking out an HttpServletRequest which sends some form data to my servlet as a MimeMultiPart.  In my servlet I call `request.getInputStream()` as follows:

```
mimeMultiPart = new MimeMultipart(new ByteArrayDataSource(
                request.getInputStream(), Constants.MULTI_PART_FORM_DATA));
```

When I mock out my input stream I create an entire MimeMultiPart message and then I try to return a ServletInputStream from it in the code below

```
    //Helper function to create ServletInputStream
private ServletInputStream createServletInputStream(Object object)
        throws Exception {

    //create output stream
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteOut);

    //this part no workey
    outStream.writeObject(object);

    //create input stream
    final InputStream byteIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteOut.toByteArray());

    //create a new ServletInputStream and return it
    return new ServletInputStream() {

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return byteIn.read();
        }
    };
}

@Test
public void testDoPost() throws Exception {
    PrintWriter writer;
    writer = new PrintWriter("testSendMultiPartBatchResponse.txt");
    when(response.getWriter()).thenReturn(writer);

            //this is the mocked request
    when(request.getInputStream()).thenReturn(
            createServletInputStream(multiPartResponse));

. . .
```

now when I run this test I receive the following error on `outStream.writeObject(object)`:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)

    . . .
```

it's not necessary to post the rest of the stack trace, I'm pretty sure the problem is that MimeMultiPart is not serializable, but I don't know how to rectify this.  Is there another way to mock out the request?  I am at a loss :(

Comment: How do you plan to use the `MimeMultipart` object later in your test? Maybe you should mock at a higher level (i.e. mock a component, which gets `MimeMultiPart` based on request).

Comment: the message is parsed out and validated, I don't think this is a good way to test the servlet behavior either, but it's not my call.  I'm just a monkey   \\_(o.O)_/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
multiPartResponse.writeTo (os);
final ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream (os.toByteArray ());
when(request.getInputStream()).thenReturn(new ServletInputStream() {
        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return is.read();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! that got me over the hump...  as usual I was making things harder than they had to be.  I also tweaked your code a little since request.getInputStream() expects a ServletInputStream rather than ByteArrayInputStream... I edited your answer to reflect my changes.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Ben Glasser, I still think it is a good idea to turn it into a static method the takes an object and returns the stream... as your question shows you were doing.